# Sources for Python Codes to do some aerodynamic Calculations

Tags: aerodynamics, fixed-wing

I am currently working to design a wing. I basically want the Python code which would take the coordinates of the airfoil (.dat file), freestream velocity, Span (b), planform of the wing as input, and give all the characteristics of the wing-like Variation of lift and lift coefficient, drag, etc along the span and variation with angle of attack.

I don't think this is the kind of question I can ask here. But, if it isn't, then pls tell me where to post this query. If you feel like you can help, pls do.

I have googled but the sources were too messy and didn't have a good presentation of the code.

Comment: Everything you need is very well described in the classic [Low-Speed Aerodynamics by Katz & Plotkin](https://books.google.it/books/about/Low_Speed_Aerodynamics.html?id=RblgQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). Have fun with it 

Comment: Searching [python aerodynamics library](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+aerodynamics+library&complete=0) provide several solutions, that you can evaluate, looking at the documentation: AeroPy, AeroSandbox, libxfoil, ... and you can look at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=airfoil) and [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org) repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As @sophit alludes, you could certainly write a code to do this kind of calculation yourself.  You would learn the most about the theory and implementation.  I recommend you do this at some point.

There are also lots of Python or Matlab codes like this laying around.  You're looking for a lifting line theory (LLT) or vortex lattice code (VLM).  Some of the raw codes are suspect, others are meant for an experienced user to hack on, and yet others are meant to be used as a turnkey tool.  Good luck figuring out which you've found.

There are also some other tools that are clearly meant to be used without having to write code.  These include AVL, XFLR5, Tornado, and VSPAERO.  They each have their pros and cons -- mostly in how easy it is to set up and get to a first solution.

Your teacher or advisor likely has a preferred tool -- one that they are familiar with and will be able to give you advice.  You might want to start there, that way you know you can get help nearby.